# Logitech MX Anywhere 2 not working, Bluetooth is not present in settings or anywhere

Tags: windows, bluetooth

I have an HP Notebook running Windows 10 and a Logitech MX Anywhere 2, which will not connect to my computer anymore.
When I got it, `I plugged in the andapter` and it worked just fine.
But I made a stupid mistake and connected it to my iPhone just to see if it would work. It doesn’t so I would advise you not to try it, but now when I try to use it on my computer it will not work. And when I go to settings and Bluetooth, the on/off slider is simply not there. Help?

Comment: "connected it to my iPhone" : What did you use to connect them

Comment: I used Bluetooth

Answer (score 5):

Instead of updating drivers, this is what I had to do to make it work (Logitech MX Anywhere 2, connecting to Windows 10) (this solution is based on my system where I have Bluetooth and also Unifying receiver both operational):

1. Logitech Unifying Software: Advanced, choosing Anywhere 2 and Un-pair.
2. Reboot.
3. Choosing 1, 2 or 3 from the mouse's bottom button. Then pressing and holding the button down again for 3 seconds to enable pairing mode.
4. "Bluetooth and other devices settings" / + Add Bluetooth or other device, MX Anywhere 2, Connect, started working.

(I do not know why before step 1, as apparently Unifying Software had already paired, there was no mouse movement whatsoever.)

Answer (score 2):

The `Logitech MX Anywhere 2` can connect 3 ways: USB,Bluetooth and via Unifying adapter.

I think the inital connection between the mouse and the unifying adapter is broken or may be you used the `easy switch button` to select another channel (1,2,3)

See which channel is active by the led on the bottom side.

I suggest you reinstall the unifying software and follow the instruction for example this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HGz9CDMvZWE)

Comment: This did not help me at all, as when I plug in the Unifying Adapter it does nothing. The green light on it lights up and it says it’s on channel one, and when I switch to any other channel it still does nothing. I cannot connect it via Vluetooth as the on or off switch does not appear in the Bluetooth and other devices setting.

Comment: The Unifying adapter **is not** bluetooth based but uses RF 2.4 GHz band. Use the Unifying software to connect.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind
I found the solution. All you have to do is download the Logitech unifying app, click your mouse and click update.

Comment: Lol, **you** found out? That's what I  told you to do.

Answer (score 0):

"Logitech MX Anywhere 2" also failed on my Windows 10 machine. Installing the Logitech unifying app (as suggested by Aids McGee) did not resolve the issue.

After updating the Bluetooth driver, the mouse worked again - here is how-to:

1. Open Device Manager
2. Find the Bluetooth device ("Bluetooth" is only visible in Device Manager if the computer has hardware-support for Bluetooth)
3. "Update driver"
4. "Search automatically for updated driver software"

Then go to:

- Settings -> "Bluetooth & other devices"
- "Add Bluetooth or other device"
- You should now see "Logitech MX Anywhere 2".
- Add the device and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth (Intel Wireless host chip in my case) Driver update solved my problem. Kind of an obvious answer but often forgotten when something stops working after working fine for years.

Answer (score 0):

"Logitech MX Anywhere 2" also failed on my Windows 10 machine.
I did this without using the unifying antenna, since the MX anywhere 2s has the option to connect directly

Open Device Manager
Find the Bluetooth device ("Bluetooth" is only visible in Device Manager if the computer has hardware-support for Bluetooth)
"disable device"
"Senable device"
Then go to:

Settings -> "Bluetooth & other devices"
"Add Bluetooth or other device"
You should now see "Logitech MX Anywhere 2".
Add the device and you're done.